# html not parsing as php in wamp

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, wamp

I am  using this snippet in my .htaccess file to parse html as php:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

this is working fine in my website(online) but not in my localhost (using WAMP latest version)..
but if I change the above code to:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt)$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

then, this is working fine in my localhost but not in my website..
I have to add/remove the `5` in `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` to work in either one side.

Please, help me..

Comment: Probably the php version in your localhost is not 5?

Comment: no... I am using PHP 5.3.1 in localhost...

Comment: @Vaibhav Gupta - What is the supported mime in `mime.types` ?

Comment: @Vaibhav Gupta - Inside apache directory, there is a file with name mime.types. You can open the file and check both application/x-httpd-php5 & application/x-httpd-php are specified. If only application/x-httpd-php is specified, it explain application/x-httpd-php5 does not work

Comment: @ajreal - i have checked the mime.types file and both application/x-httpd-php5 & application/x-httpd-php are not specified... :(

Comment: Make sure you are using correct module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369781/htaccess-rule-to-parse-php-in-html-files-not-working

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your local httpd.conf file, and add the mime modules you need:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .txt
</IfModule>
```

This should work for your local host. If you can't configure your server this way, and since your .htaccess works there, use the .htaccess config for your server only.

Comment: To access your httpd.conf file, open wamp menu from tray and go to Apache->httpd.conf

Comment: ok... but what I want is to able to parse html as php using:
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5