# htaccess rule to parse php in html files not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, dreamhost

can't for the life of me work out why this isn't working - on a dreamhost server, I've created an htaccess file and added `AddHandler php5-cgi .html .htm` to allow php in html files, as per the dreamhost docs. On an identical dreamhost package, I've done the same thing for another site and it worked perfectly, but in this case it just won't parse the php! Is there anything I could have missed here which could be causing the problem? The htaccess is in the web root and isn't being overridden by anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your server using suPHP rather than mod_php or plain php-cgi?

Try using

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

instead.

## Postscript

Shared Hosting services use UID based separation on individual accounts from each others.  Most use **suPHP**, but some use **suEXEC**.  They will use one of these.  Both act as a su wrapper around php-cgi so you can't tell from the phpinfo()as its PHP scripting engine as this will report **`Server API`**  `CGI/FastCGI` in both cases.  For CGI initiated scripts, phpinfo doesn't report on the Apache config.  You need either to look at your hosting provider's FAQ or possibly try:

```
 <?php
 header( "Content-Type: text/plain");
 echo system('grep -iR LoadModule /etc/httpd /etc/apache2');
```

The hosting provider's support forums / FAQ might give specific configuration advice here.  Have you tried them?

Comment: Hi, it's running as CGI. I've tried those options you've mentioned anyway, just to rule them out. If I run phpinfo(), Server API is CGI.

Comment: Sorry, but for the reasons in my PS above, this conclusion may be wrong.

Comment: I've just checked the Dreamhost wiki.  It uses suEXEC \([here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Suexec)\), but comments in passing that it infact now uses FastCGI \([here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP_FastCGI)\).  You need to set up for FastCGI.  This is one to resolve on http://discussion.dreamhost.com/

Comment: My personal experience was that `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` prompted me to download the file and `AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm` did not run the PHP.  `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html` used PHP 5.2.x but the original `AddHandler php5-cgi .html .htm` used the PHP I had set for my site (5.4.x).

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

The above setting will work if the apache is picking php as a module.

```
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

above will work if apache is executing php  as CGI?

there is no harm i would say to put both of the above conditions together but try one over other and see if it work for you.

read more [here](http://jaspreetchahal.org/html-as-php-htaccess/) in this article I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem as you but I just put this `AddType php .html .htm` to my .htaccess, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working for only like this:

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php .htm
```