# apache wont treat html file as php even though i've already added an AddHandler

Tags: php, html, apache

I have already configured apache's main config file and added

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

but apache still won't treat .html files as php files.

Comment: yes, i've even restarted the computer.

Comment: have a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369781/htaccess-rule-to-parse-php-in-html-files-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369781/htaccess-rule-to-parse-php-in-html-files-not-working)

Comment: alright thanks! i'll check it out

Comment: @shatheesh by the way, i am trying to run it locally. the chosen answer was referring to a hosting service.

Comment: yeah I read that, But also have a look into this comment in that post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9369832/2905249](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9369832/2905249)

Comment: A bit of a sub question here; Why would someone want to set it up this way rather than just requesting pages as .php? Thanks :D

Comment: @Stretch to hide the language they're using when the webpage is viewed in a browser.

Comment: @shatheesh i do not understand that PHP CGI thing. i've checked my phpinfo but i can't find it there.

Comment: You can hide that with a simple RewriteRule. Changing the handler for html files only adds unnessecary overhead when serving actual static content.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider what are you referring to?