# Simple PHP code wont work in HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to make HTML code that has PHP embedded. The PHP code allows me to display pictures from a specific folder in /var/www/html/images. When the extension is .php for the file it works but when I change it to HTML it doesn't. I really need it in HTML format but images aren't displaying I receive this

[Error Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IId6i.jpg)

[Error Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2cf2.jpg)

Code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Gallery from Folder Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
li{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}

-->
</style>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="Return to Menu" 
    onclick=window.history.go(-2);
    </form>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <?php
        $dirname = "images/";
        $images = scandir($dirname);
        arsort($images);
        $ignore = array(".", "..");
        foreach($images as $curimg){
            if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"$dirname$curimg\"><img src='img.php?src=$dirname$curimg&w=300&zc=1' alt='' /></a></li>\n ";
            }

        }               
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369781/htaccess-rule-to-parse-php-in-html-files-not-working

Comment: cos HTML file wont process PHP code, need to use extension like .phtml for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312349/2520628