# Wamp Server Not Parsing htm Files As PHP

Tags: apache, wamp

I know this question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352483/html-not-parsing-as-php-in-wamp). I am trying to use a script in my localhost. The script contains .htm files and an .htaccess file with the following code to parse those .htm files as PHP.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .php .html
```

Now this is not working at all and i get a blank web page whenever i run it from my localhost. i.e "localhost/paystill_enterprise" and it give me blank webpage.

Now i have tried every solution i could find on internet like editing httpd.conf file etc. Here are some of the solutions i have tried.

1- I have tried editing httdp.conf and have added the following code one by one

```
 <IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .txt
 </IfModule>

 <FilesMatch "\.html$">
   ForceType application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>

 <FilesMatch "\.htm$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>
```

2- Tried adding these lines of code one by one in my .htaccess file

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

 AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

 RemoveHandler .html .htm
 AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

No matter what i use, always get a blank page for "localhost/paystill_enterprise".

Note:
Sometimes it also happens that when i type the address "localhost/paystill_enterprise", the browsers asks me to save the file i.e the browser tries to download it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

The one time I did this all I did was add these 2 instructions to me `.htaccess` file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

So remove all your other changes and try just this one change as your other chnages may interfere with this.